# Why is ë percent encoded to %EB but also to %C3%AB?

Tags: php, character-encoding, percent-encoding

When I enter ë into a form on my web application, this is percent encoded by Google Chrome to %C3%AB.

When I use PHP's urlencode('ë'); This is encoded into %EB.

Why are the encodings different?

How can I encode with the same encoding as Google Chrome with PHP 4?

Comment: `ë` has different byte representations in different charsets.

Comment: Are you really on php 4? Anyway, you should look at encoding everything (db, db connection, html) in utf8, that will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: i think %EB is representation in ISO-8859-1 charset, and %C3%AB is UTF-8 representation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`%EB` is the ISO-8859-1 form (a single character).

`%C3%AB` is the UTF-8 form (`e` + `¨`).

It [should work out of the box](http://codepad.org/wMtP6dX8) (if you use a newer version of PHP and UTF-8 for your files).

Comment: @i.amniels: I have no idea, just set up your forms to always submit using UTF-8 (`accept-charset` attribute) and you'll be fine. Also, you should really upgrade your PHP version.